# Why can't I get the path where the executable resides?

Tags: vb.net, path

I've done a VB.Net app and I need to get the executable path. I use "Application.StartupPath" and it works fine on Debug and installed on my machine, but on a client's PC it sometimes returns the AppData path! How do I consistently get the path where the executable is actually stored (C:\Program Files[program name])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).[GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)().[Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```